# Does Password Harvesting Happen in Servers?

Tags: passwords

Maybe someone can explain why my concern is not realistic.  If I create a browser-based app with a login (let's say I'm Facebook or Microsoft), why wouldn't I store all the wrong passwords people type?   Some of them have to be valid passwords for other apps and I (if I were dishonest) could probably sell them.   From what I've read most apps do not encrypt passwords in the browser prior to sending to the server.

Comment: It's a bit unreasonable to expect companies like FB/Microsoft to get involved in this because of the repurcussions of doing such nasty stuff.

Comment: There of course can be other sites that might be doing that.

Comment: While some sites will store every keystroke, I'd think this is one area where they would avoid it.  It's a liability to store passwords... whether they were mistyped or not.  The lawyers would probably make them disclose this in their terms of service.  But of course a crook is a crook, so if the site is run by criminals all bets are off.

Comment: It's very common for people to inadvertently type their password in the *User* field. Logs will often show something like: **Failed login for *pass123* at 0800**.  **Login by *Sally* at 0801**. *Guess what Sally's password is?*

Answer (score 2):

You could. It is a valid concern for sites with owners that are under less scrutiny than Microsoft and Facebook. There are a number of points that make this a less likely option though.

- Many will be just typo's of the right password (sECRET in stead of Secret, oops, capslock etc.)
- Some will just be the previous password.
- Many people use the same password for more than one site. Harvesting the right password is therefore much more efficient than harvesting the wrong passwords.
- You still need to try those passwords and having a lot of wrong passwords will make this step unnecessary time consuming.

So, though possible, it is unlikely to happen because it is so inefficient.